# InfoBox MapControl WPF (not Silverlight)

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

Is it possible to show a floating "infobox" when you press a push pin using "[Bing Maps Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Control, Version 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27165)"?

I can create push pins and I can detect when they are clicked, but I don’t have any idea how to show a floating window.  It sounds like I can use a InfoBox, but I don't have this...is this only available in Silverlight?

It is using Visual Studio 2010 for a [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application.

Comment: The download link is (effectively) broken: *"We're sorry, this download is no longer available."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Canvas & Thumb:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF" 
        x:Class="WpfApplication15.MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <maps:Map/>
        <Canvas>
            <Grid Name="grid"
                  Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
                  Width="200" Height="100">
                <!-- Your control begin -->
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
                <!-- Your control end -->
                <Thumb Name="thumbMove">
                    <Thumb.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Thumb.Template>
                </Thumb>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>

thumbMove.DragDelta += (s, e) =>
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(grid, Canvas.GetLeft(grid) + e.HorizontalChange);
    Canvas.SetTop(grid, Canvas.GetTop(grid) + e.VerticalChange);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've no idea how WPF actually works designwise so once I understand where to put the markup I'll let you know.